# ESP8266WebServer Response time jumps from 0.03 to 1 second if incoming POST payload is >1024 bytes

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to post instructions to set LED color values and I've hit a wall. I'm posting a JSON array from my PC and then using that array to set LEDs accordingly on my NodeMCU. I'm using a listener for incoming data `server.on("/command", commandHandler);`

The response time of me posting, receiving, parsing and iterating the JSON array is usually 0.03 seconds. However if I POST to my NodeMCU more than 1024 bytes the response time is always 1 second regardless if I post 1025 bytes or more.

I could send multiple payloads of <1024 bytes however the huge jump from 0.03s to 1s just because of 1 byte makes me wonder if there is some kind of setting I could use to overcome this problem?

Here's what the times look like:

> Sending 256 bytes Execution 0.02 s.
>
> Sending 512 bytes Execution 0.02 s.
>
> Sending 768 bytes Execution 0.02 s.
>
> Sending 1024 bytes Execution 0.02 s.
>
> Sending 1280 bytes Execution 1.00 s.
>
> Sending 1536 bytes Execution 0.99 s.
>
> Sending 1792 bytes Execution 1.00 s.
>
> Sending 2048 bytes Execution 1.00 s.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() {

  // Initialization 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("ssid", "pass");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) delay(500);

  // Listeners
  server.on("/command", commandHandler);
  server.begin();

}


// POST request to set
void commandHandler() {

  DynamicJsonBuffer JSONBuffer;
  JsonObject& json = JSONBuffer.parseObject(server.arg("plain"));

  if (!json.success()) {
    server.send(200, "text/json", "{\"status\":\"Invalid JSON\"}");
    return;
  }

  // LEDs
  if(json["leds"]) {
    // .. do stuff with leds
  }

  server.send(200, "text/json", "{\"status\":\"Done\"}"); 
}

// Main loop
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code is actually slow? HTTP parsing? JSON parsing?

Comment: @gre_gor I've removed the JSON element and the problem persists. I've opened an issue for this on github https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4500